# Domain driven design pattern clarification

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Hi all 
Im trying to build a solution using a DDD approach. Ive created a set of entities, and some datamappers i use to remove the data persistence dependency from the entities. 
Is it correct of me, to use a datamapper like a "finder" class, i have methods like

getById()
getUsersByRanking() 
getByLastName()

or should the datamapper not contain specialized finder methods and only use getById()?

Is it correct of me to assume that the Repository pattern is used to remove those "specialized" finder methods that i have added to the datamapper, and instead give the client a Query Language that they can use instead to find entities by other means than the ID?.

I really hope someone can help me clarify how these patterns interact with each other Domain model, Datamapper, Data presistence, Repository.

Ive read alot in the Martin Fowler POEAA but having a hard time connecting the dots :)

Comment: What language are you using? what you mapping too (what type of repository SQL DB, Object DB, memory DB, Document Oriented DB etc)?

Comment: Dont the patterns have the same meaning, no matter what language / data persistence im using?. But at the moment i trying to implement this into a PHP application, using a relational database (MySQL).

Comment: Well speaking to different vendors, each has their own take on where Domains go. The domain stuff could be modelled in implementation either on the Sql db or in your php. I know next to nothing about php, does it support a full N-tiered design? If you model and design your application with an N-tiered design the pieces fit together a lot easier. For example the DB is hidden behind the Repository Class, and the DataMapper maps the DB  to your Domain Model written in PHP I take it. All interactions in your application would then be done via the Repository Class.

Comment: Basicly what im trying to understand is, if i need a repository or my datamapper can have the responsibility of query the database for specialized criteria. As i read in DDD the respository is the entry point to all domain models, and the respository uses a datamapper to create the entity objects, and a identity map to keep track on the them. Is that a correct assumtion.

Comment: What your describing there is a solution based on an ORM (Object relation mapper). The repositories job is to interface between your code and the outside world. The responsibility of the data-mapper(s) is to bring this data in and map it to your repository objects. Take a look at some ORMs, might help you understand whats trying to be acheived, although most ORMS don't cater for Entities, but pseudo table structures. Microsoft Entity Framework 4.0 is close to the pattern, or tries to be :).

Comment: The repository has to be designed to handle concurrency, disconnected data, disparate data source. It has to be able to know when its got stale data. It usually is built out of arrays or similar constructs. I would not advise in rolling your own though as the relationships between entities and tracking become a real pain.

Comment: The data-mapper should be able to perform any sort of query you can muster on the database and return back data mapped to your entity correctly and with all the relations in place. It should be invisible to your system and act as transparently as possible, hiding the fact that calls the the db are in a different language than your internal structures, or the structures of the entity.

Comment: I personally would look at ORMS for this. I did build my own once, but as I started developing it, I started to realise how much work was required, simple arrays were a doddle to manage, but it gets pretty hairy when you start implementing relations. The last project I worked on I used Plain Old Objects for my repository and Microsoft Entity Framework 1.0. It was ok, but the Framework was missing some major parts. I think (or hope) these have now been rectified. I can't help you with PHP as I never have gotten into it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it helped abit, my current problem is i cant see a clear distinction between a datamapper and a repository, they seem very alike, in the descriptions from Martin Fowler's POEAA, maybe the distinction is hard for me to see because ive never needed the benefits a Repository pattern can bring!

Comment: Very true, they usual come into their own in Large Scale solutions where there are multiple apps where the Entity becomes centralised and caters for more than one app. In a single app scenario the entity stuff folds into an ORM. Its only when you see it from a bigger picture that it makes sense. Take a look at N-tier architecture, see where the problems lie there and step back into entities and they make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets's sat that respositories are entry point for entities in DDD. you can create abstract one and then specialize it to each entity. So you can ask a repository every time you need to get an entity. The datamapper is a solution to map entities with their database representations or any other storages. So I guess  that datamapper has to be hidden behind the repository pattern.

Comment: As i talked with WeNeedAnswers in the above comments, my problem is that the distinction between when to add the Repository abstraction around my datamapper is very hard to see, many examples i see on the net, looks like they are using datamapper's and repositories interchangely, many people talk about the Repository is adding a Collection like interface to your domain objects, but as i see it thats what the datamapper does aswell.

Comment: @madsleejensen you should not interchange Repository and DM 'cause at least DM is NOT DDD's concept. As  WeNeedAnswers wrote "The responsibility of the data-mapper(s) is to bring this data in and map it to your repository objects". So you may consider DM as specific mechanism  behind Repository concept.